# Issue with tar -N command not filtering dates correctly

Tags: linux, tar

I have this tar command I am trying to run -

`tar -N '2016-01-01' -jcvf archive.tar.bz2 /home/myhome`

Inside of the home directory, I have the following files that should be filtered

```
-rwx------.  1   1000   1000    89097 Dec  3  2011 automysqlbackup
-rw-------.  1   1000   1000    11858 Nov 21  2011 automysqlbackup.conf
```

However, when I look at the command output, they are still there -

```
tar: Option --after-date: Treating date `2016-01-01' as 2016-01-01 00:00:00
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
...
/home/bamboo/automysqlbackup
/home/bamboo/automysqlbackup.conf
...
```

Why is it not filtering these files by dates correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the gnu documentation:
https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/after.html

> [...] causes tar to only work on files whose data modification **or status change time**s are newer [...]
>
> If you only want tar to make the date comparison **based on modification** of the file's data (rather than status changes), then use the `--newer-mtime=date' option.

So I guess if you check your files with `ls -lc /home/myhome` rather than `ls -l` you'll see their ctime (that would be status in the documentation) is newer than your date

ctime changes when the inode changes, including but not limited to actions such as chmod, ln (hardlinking), and of course creation, like restoration from a tar archive.

So try this instead:

```
tar jcvf archive.tar.bz2 --newer-mtime=2016-01-01 /home/myhome
```